# Adding a Show All Button to a CheckBoxList That Is Being Populated

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

Suppose I have the following table:

[image]

and the following `CheckBoxList`:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="MyCheckBoxList"/>
```

In the code-behind, I populate it as follows:

```
MyCheckBoxList.DataSource = from c in EMPLOYEE
                            select c.NAME;
```

I will then end up with the following:

[image]

Now, what can I do so that I will end up with the following instead:

[image]

I do not want to touch the table to achieve this. I have tried `MyCheckBoxList.Items.Add("Show All");` and then populating the list to no avail. I have also tried adding it last, but it will be at the bottom rather than the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [`AppendDataBoundItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx) to `true` and add this item as static `ListItem`:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="MyCheckBoxList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="true">Show All</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple `union`:

```
MyCheckBoxList.DataSource = (from x in new string[] { "Select All" }
                            select x).Union(
                            from c in EMPLOYEE
                            select c.NAME);
```